# Find and remove list from list

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to find some post that has done what i'm trying to do, but i can't find anything.

I've got this list, i.e.

```
rows =
[['Jan 31', ' 2014 19:48:30.096606000', '0x10', '0x00000000', '0x0f7864ef', '0x0f7864f1', '', 'blahblah', 'other \n'], 
['Jan 31', ' 2014 19:48:30.829329000', '0x10', '0x00000000', '0x0f920978', '0x0f92097a', '', 'blahblah', 'anotherr \n']]
```

i need to find AND remove a list from the list searching by the 5th item like this:

```
search == '0x0f7864ef'
if any(e[4] == search for e in rows):
```

If the searched var exists then i get a True, but I don't know how to remove it from "rows". And doing something like `rows.remove(e)` just returns an error

I have tried looping over a set and removing when found, but i got an error. Also, I would rather not to have to loop through the set/list. This is what i tried:

```
>>> a = {( '1','da','vi' ), (2,'be','vi') }
>>> for item in a:
...   if 'da' in item:
...     a.remove(item)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
>>> a
set([(2, 'be', 'vi')])
```

Even though the item was removed, I got an error...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never insert/remove elements in a list while you're iterating on it.
Instead you could use a higher-order function, like `filter`.

In Python 2.7:

```
>>> filter(lambda e: e[4] != '0x0f7864ef', rows)
[['Jan 31',
  ' 2014 19:48:30.829329000',
  '0x10',
  '0x00000000',
  '0x0f920978',
  '0x0f92097a',
  '',
  'blahblah',
  'anotherr \n']]
```

In Python 3.x (`filter` returns a generator):

```
>>> filter(lambda e: e[4] != '0x0f7864ef', rows)
<builtins.filter at 0x7f76e2432810>

>>> list(filter(lambda e: e[4] != '0x0f7864ef', rows))
[['Jan 31',
  ' 2014 19:48:30.829329000',
  '0x10',
  '0x00000000',
  '0x0f920978',
  '0x0f92097a',
  '',
  'blahblah',
  'anotherr \n']]
```

For the sake of readibility you might prefer to define a named function instead of using a lambda.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Using a lamda like would return the list *not* matching, and the other war around it would return the matchin row. If my list is very big, creating a new list filtering out the matching id, would that be smart, if i have hundreds of thousand of items in the list? I would first need to get the item that matches and save it somewhere (file) and then execute it again to filter OUT the mathing item, storing the list on a different var, copying that again to the original var and then doing it all over again for the next value... What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the complete problem. I thought you just needed to remove elements in a specific position, matching a condition.

Comment: This is the answer that pointed in the right direction. What I did was to filter out and filter in. I filtered in to get the matching, and filtered out to remove the matching. Thanks @nadir !

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new list with the items filtered, like this:

```
new_list = [item for item in rows if search not in item]
```

This is a *list comprehension*, which is an expression that evaluates as a list. The longer way to write the above is in a for + if loop, like this:

```
new_list = []
for item in rows:
   if search not in item:
       new_list.append(item)
```

It is very poor practice to modify a list which you are looping over, which is why the standard practice is to create a new list; either with a list comprehension or with a more traditional loop.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I would rather not create new lists, as i will be doing it a lot. This is for very big files which contain REQUEST-RESPONSE logs that I want to match. When I see a new request I add it to the list and when I get a RESPONSE i need to look up the corresponding request and remove it from the list. The REQUEST-REPONSES total in the millions (about 3 million), so the list will be getting bigger and bigger if I don't remove requests already matched. What do you think?

Comment: Use a `set`, which will speed up your lookups; whatever you do, don't modify the list inside your loop.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for maintaining a list over set ? as Burhan said, set will speed up your lookups as Set lookup is O(1) just like dictionary and you can easily remove using set.remove or set.pop.

Comment: No reason. The point is I don't know how to remove an item once found in the set/list with "any"

Comment: So, you are trying to make sure every request has been responded ? right and every request is unique or it can be dupli ?

Comment: @yopy there's duplicate IDs on the reponses, but not on the requests, this is due to a lack of an ack that sometimes happens. All requests IDs are unique.